# Python Pandas ordering strings

Tags: python, string, pandas

I am trying to take a final/summary dataframe and create a written summary by concatenating text with numbers/data from various series from the dataframe.  The below written script is what I would like to see

```
Team   Stat1   Stat2   Stat3  total   increase/decrease     written script
red    8       -6      2       4      increase              the increase is driven by stat1 8, stat2 -6 and stat3 2
blue   -4       2      1       -1     decrease              the decrease is driven by stat1 -4, stat2 2 and stat3 1
green  2       10      3       15     increase              the increase is driven by stat2 10, stat3 3 and stat1 2
```

The increase/decrease column is based upon an if statement looking at the total column

The script per team needs to be ordered by the largest stat number in order of absolute value from largest to smallest.  I can put the concatenation and figures together, but i do not know how to order a list of strings or assign values to a series of strings in different columns.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda function will help to meet this requirement.

```
def summaryText(x):
    text = 'the {} is driven by {},{} and {}'.format(x['total'],\
                                                 'Stat1'+ " "+str(x['Stat1']),\
                                                 " "+'Stat2'+ " "+str(x['Stat2']),\
                                                 " "+'Stat3'+" "+ str(x['Stat3']))
    return text
df['summary'] = df.apply(lambda x: summaryText(x),axis=1)
df['increase/decrease'] = df.apply(lambda x : 'increase' if x['total'] > 0 else 'decrease',axis=1)
```

Although both the one liner and calling functions essentially contains same thing, I wanted to share the screenshot of %timeit magic as below for total column check.
![loading image][![PercenttimeitMagic Screenshot][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGq5U.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGq5U.jpg)

Comment: Muthu, this is helpful!  But is there a way to order Stat1,Stat2, Stat3 by largest to smallest using absolute value based on their numerical value?

Comment: def summaryText(x):
    `for x in df.itertuples():
         lst= []
         lst=[abs(x[2]),abs(x[3]),abs(x[4])]
         s = sorted(lst)
    text = 'the {} is driven by {},{} and {}'.format(x['total'],s[0],s[1],s[2])
    return text `

Comment: I was able to sort the values but fetching column name might require some more change in the code.  
I am sure there is a better and elegant way to achieve this.
Hope my answers help to some extent ;)